# "Expected operands to be a string or number type" Angular

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, I have this warning !

> "Expected operands to be a string or number type"

[image]

`contentType` is a string

when I remove 'data:' everything is ok

Comment: try logging typeof for all the parts and see if one of them is a custom type

Comment: Can we see the declaration of `event`?

Comment: event is interface with eventImageNavigation variable. eventImageNavigation is EventImage interface with contentType variable. contentType variable is a string... Anyway, the problem shouldn't be there because by removing 'data:' + the warning disappears!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the good way is:

```
src="data:{{ event.eventObj.eventImageNavigation.contentType }};base64,{{ event.eventObj.eventImageNavigation.data }}"
```

Comment: what if I have to use a pipe over generated string!